# Calling Non default Constructor to a non pointer variable

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

I am using a library which have the following statement in the example -

```
SqlDatabase db(DB_FILE_NAME, false);
```

The constructor is defined as

```
SqlDatabase(const char* szFile, bool useExclusiveWAL = true );
```

However I want to make this object as a member variable. Which means I want to separate the definition and declaration separately. I can do it like this -

```
SqlDatabase* db;
db = new SqlDatabase(DB_FILE_NAME, false);
```

But what if I don't want to make this a non-pointer variable, just like the example? How would I do it?
For example:

```
SqlDatabase db; //doesn't work in cpp, since there isn't any default constructor, but I can put it in header
db = SqlDatabase(DB_FILE_NAME, false); //Doesn't work
```

PS: I am sure this is too basic, but I'd still like to know this. I have searched SO, but dunno what this kind of statements are called.

**Update:**
I've just checked the linked question, but I didn't get any link between what I asked and that member initialization list. I just want the declaration in header and a separate definition in cpp. I don't think this has been answered in the linked question.

Comment: `SomeConstructor() : db(DB_FILENAME, false) {}`

Comment: @MikeSeymour: _"However I want to make this object as a member variable."_

Comment: @MikeSeymour From the question: *However I want to make this object as a member variable.*

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Indeed, my reading comprehension sems to be failing. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: lolz ;p

Comment: @Borgleader: Please do not write answers in comments.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit is there a rule against it?

Comment: @Borgleader: It's completely self-evident that the commenting feature is not for answers and that you are promoting a "chat room" or "forum" style approach to Stack Overflow, which is bad. But if you really need documentation, [here it is](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253045/560648).

Comment: _"I didn't get any link between what I asked and that member initialization list"_ Then read it again.

Comment: _"I just want the declaration in header and a separate definition in cpp"_ Just because "the marked question" doesn't teach you every single facet of C++ doesn't mean it doesn't answer your question. The answer is _use the member initialisation list_. Now once you've done that, recall that you can define a constructor elsewhere from its declaration, and you're good to go. Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: I never read any for C++, that's why I am asking here. Anyways I got the answer from an article. The answers to the linked question are still confusing. Thanks for giving the clue.